# Split by attributes function only splits some, but not all values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, split-by-attribute

I have a shapefile that has GPS coordinates and categories such as ID. I wanted to split my shapefiles into separate shapefiles for each ID. When I use split by attributes, it only extracts/splits some of the data (IDs), and misses many others of them. So for example, I have about 20 different types of individuals in my data and I wanted arcgis to separate data on all those 20 individuals into 20 shapefiles. It separates only 10 and just simply doesn't do the others, why?

Examples of the one's separated: BW1019_2009; BW1017_2011; BW1017_2010; BW1023_2010

Examples of the one's not separated: 2011013 - 2010; 2020095 - 2012, 2019432 - 2020; 2019039 - 2019

As a solution, I separated all the one's that Arcgis refused to split by attributes into a separate file and then tried to do a "separate by attributes" and it just simply produced nothing. I don't understand how whatever the "id" is, makes any difference in whether it separates or not.

Comment: It doesn't want shapefile name that starts with number.

Answer (score -2):

I tried everything, and then just moved to QGIS, it worked absolutely fine there. In QGIS you have a tool called "split" and you can split by the column of your choice and there are no errors or problems that I have encountered.

Comment: You didn't try conforming to the "leading alpha in a name" requirement.